# Is there any way to connect to specific readonly replica in Azure SQL DB Premium Read Scale-Out?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to know is there any way to connect to one of readonly replicas?

I know if Azure SQL data base is Premium type and Read Scale-out is Enabled, I can have two readnonly replicas. For connecting to ANY of those replicas, I just need to put ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly; in my connection string.

Attached link about Read scale-out replicas
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out

Also I know that there are some load balancer that can switch from request from one readonly replica to another.

So, is there some approach to define what replica should I use, Replica1 or Replica2 for (for ex.) Analytics and PowerBi reports accordingly at the same time?

Server=tcp:.database.windows.net;Database=;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;User ID=;Password=;Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True;

Answer (score 0):

At any given time only one of the replicas is accessible by the ReadOnly sessions and you cannot specify which one.

Answer (score 0):

No, not at this time - Per the documentation (in a 'Note' about half way down: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out)

> At any given time only one of the AlwaysON replicas is accessible by the ReadOnly sessions.

It seems that the system will choose which replica to use for the connection/session when the connection is initiated.